# Spotfire moving average by group

Tags: average, mdx, spotfire, tibco, moving-average

I'm using a software named spotfire in which I can set "custom expressions" with MDX. By the way, **it isn't a requirement to know this software to answer this question**. I expect general answers that could help other people as well even if they don't use spotfire.

I need to get the moving average **for each group**. I have a lot of groups, I can't make a table per group.

Below is an example of my table:

```
ID | GROUP |    DATE    | VALUE | MVG_AVG
------------------------------------------
a  |   A   | 05/10      |   5   |          
b  |   B   | 05/10      |   4   |              
c  |   A   | 05/11      |   9   |         
d  |   B   | 05/11      |   7   |         
e  |   B   | 05/12      |   7   |         
f  |   B   | 05/13      |   7   |         
g  |   A   | 05/12      |   1   |    
h  |   B   | 05/14      |   1   |
```

I found the **LastPeriods** function, but I can't get it work for each group. I use n=3 for the function.

Here is the same table with expected results for moving average :

```
ID | GROUP |    DATE    | VALUE | MVG_AVG
------------------------------------------
a  |   A   | 05/10      |   5   |    5       #because no previous value (for group A)
b  |   B   | 05/10      |   4   |    4          
c  |   A   | 05/11      |   9   |    5       # =(5+9+1)/3
d  |   B   | 05/11      |   7   |    6     
e  |   B   | 05/12      |   7   |    7     
f  |   B   | 05/13      |   7   |    5     
g  |   A   | 05/12      |   1   |    1       #because no next value (for group A)
h  |   B   | 05/14      |   1   |    1
```

---

Here is my current custom expression in Spotfire, it doesn't take into account groups:

```
Sum([VALUE]) OVER (LastPeriods(3,[DATE])) / 3
```

Comment: I dont get where are you taking your MVG_AVG from

Comment: @JacekSierajewski this column MVG_AVG is the calculated column I would need. It performs a moving average over groups.

Comment: For ID 'a' your formula is: just a. For ID 'c' your formula is: a+c+g / 3. For ID 'g' your formula is: just g so it is like for 'a'. Why is it different for 'c' ?

Comment: @JacekSierajewski because it is a moving average (with n=3, ie 3 values), that is to say the average using previous value, current value and next value. a doesn't have a previous value, and g doesn't have a next value, that's why these values are respectively a and g.

Comment: Ok, now I get it :) It seems there are many variations of the Moving avarage so it would probably make sense to explain what kind exactly you meant but it is clear for me now.